# Using `mutate_at` and `na_if` together to replace zeros with NA for only some columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

My data takes this format:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- mtcars
df <- df %>% mutate(vs_doubled = vs * 2) %>% select(mpg, cyl, vs, am, vs_doubled)

head(df)


#>    mpg cyl vs am vs_doubled
#> 1 21.0   6  0  1          0
#> 2 21.0   6  0  1          0
#> 3 22.8   4  1  1          2
#> 4 21.4   6  1  0          2
#> 5 18.7   8  0  0          0
#> 6 18.1   6  1  0          2
```

I'm trying to use `mutate_at` and `na_if` to set 0 values as NA--but only for specific columns ("vs" and "am"). I would like to leave the column "vs_doubled" with zeros in it.

I haven't quite got it right, because the following line doesn't work:

```
df <- df %>% mutate_at(.vars = c("vs", "am"), .funs = na_if(y = 0))
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update**

From `dplyr` 1.0.0 we can use `across` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(c(vs,am), na_if, 0)) %>% head

#   mpg cyl vs am vs_doubled
#1 21.0   6 NA  1          0
#2 21.0   6 NA  1          0
#3 22.8   4  1  1          2
#4 21.4   6  1 NA          2
#5 18.7   8 NA NA          0
#6 18.1   6  1 NA          2
```

---

**Original answer**

In the previous versions of `dplyr` we can use `mutate_at` :

```
df %>%  mutate_at(vars(vs,am), ~na_if(.,0)) %>% head
```

Or another way would be

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(vs,am), na_if, 0)
```

`~` is purrr-styled formula syntax whereas `.` represents value of the column. It's an alternative to anonymous function calls with which you would have written the above function as

```
df %>%  mutate_at(vars(vs,am), function(x) na_if(x, 0))
```

Also the alternative way shown does not require `~` and we can directly pass the function with additional arguments (which is 0 here for `y`).

---

And of course there are other ways to do this without using `na_if`

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(vs, am), ~replace(., . == 0, NA))
```

Or the same with base R

```
cols <- c("vs", "am")
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) replace(x, x == 0, NA))
```

Comment: It would be good to provide a basic explanation of what `~` and `.` do here. I like the `tidyverse` but it's frustrating when the answers to `tidyverse` questions often end up being "add these arbitrary symbols".

Comment: With `~na_if()`, is the `~` to indicate that the next part is a formula? It won't just take a function? I'm still trying to work out why I should have used `~` before the `na_if`. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone looking for an explanation of the `~` and `.`, I'm finding this link very useful https://suzan.rbind.io/2018/02/dplyr-tutorial-2/#mutate-at-to-change-specific-columns

Answer (score 2):

We can use `case_when` with `mutate_at`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(vs, am), ~ case_when(!. ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ .)) %>%
     head
```

Comment: I was hoping that the "vs" and "am" columns above would have NA rather than zeros. Thank you.

Comment: What does the `!.` refer to here?

Comment: @Workingdollar Here, the `.` refers to the columns values, negate with `!`) so `!.` - will return TRUE for all 0 and FALSE for others, thus 0 will be converted to NA and others remain as such as `TRUE ~ .`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to change certain values (**Values <2**) in my dataframe to NA. I have data-time in one of the columns however `na_if()` was definitely not working. I used Ronak's suggestion - my only edit is to convert the **tibble** to a dataframe.

Suggested solution:

```r
**df <**- df %>% mutate_at(vars(vs, am), ~replace(., . == 0, NA))
```

Excerpt/Application in my script:

```r
wave_T_max <- wave_T_max %>% 
      mutate_at(vars(Value), ~replace(Value, Value <2, NA))
```