# Replace all string instances of "NULL" with actual NULL or NA in a data frame

Tags: r

I wondered if there was a one liner where I could replace all instances of string "NULL" in a DF across multiple fields with just NULL or NA?

```
exampledf <- data.frame(
  a = c("NULL", "1/1/20", "2/28/20"),
  b = c("NULL", "blah", "ha"),
  c = c("NULL", "NULL", "cat")
)
```

Is there a one liner that would replace "NULL" across the entire df with NULL or NA?

Comment: Also see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51449243/5325862), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56928827/5325862), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27909000/5325862)

Comment: @camille yes,  it does thanks!

Comment: If that post solves it, you should be able to mark your own question as a duplicate of that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
exampledf[exampledf=="NULL"] <- NA
```

or with `dplyr`

```
exampledf <- exampledf %>% replace(exampledf == "NULL", NA)
```

Comment: Thanks! Leaving open for a while in case anyone has a tidyverse approach  could use within a pipe `exampledf %>%`

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
exampledf <- exampledf %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), na_if, "NULL"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace` like below

```
> replace(exampledf, exampledf == "NULL", NA)
        a    b    c
1    <NA> <NA> <NA>
2  1/1/20 blah <NA>
3 2/28/20   ha  cat
```